# What is the difference between rpi-update and sudo-apt upgrade?

Tags: apt, update

I'm wondering what the difference is between running the [git-hub obtained program](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) `rpi-update` and using `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I've checked around and cannot find the differences listed anywhere. Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These two commands are actually different. In short,

- `rpi-update` updates your device's *firmware*, while
- `apt-get update/upgrade` updates your device's *operating system*.